# Sistema de login com sessoes

Tags: php, login

EM UM SISTEMA DE LOGIN COM PHP QUAL VARIÁVEIS DEVO ARMAZENAR NAS SESSÕES? email e senha ou só o id do usuário?

Answer (score 0):

O coreto é armazenar o email/username e id, ou apenas o "id" já que com o “id” podes obter outros dados do utilizador. Não é uma boa ideia armazenar password na sessão, 1º por questão de segurança, 2ª porque não vais precisar do password para efetuar outras operações alem do login.